# Cannot uninstall webpack from react-script

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-native, npm, webpack

I was trying to make a todo-app in react, which is new to me. But after once installed webpack, npm start doesnt working. It gives me:

> my-todo-react@0.1.0 start /home/hanna/Desktop/projects/my-todo-react
>   react-scripts start

There might be a problem with the project dependency tree.
It is likely not a bug in Create React App, but something you need to fix locally.

The react-scripts package provided by Create React App requires a dependency:

"webpack": "4.19.1"

Don't try to install it manually: your package manager does it automatically.
However, a different version of webpack was detected higher up in the tree:

/home/hanna/node_modules/webpack (version: 4.20.2)

Manually installing incompatible versions is known to cause hard-to-debug issues.

If prefer to ignore this check, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That will permanently disable this message but you might encounter other issues.

To fix the dependency tree, try following the steps below in the exact order:

1. Delete package-lock.json (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.
2. Delete node_modules in your project folder.
3. Remove "webpack" from dependencies and/or devDependencies in the package.json file in your project folder.
4. Run npm install or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

In most cases, this should be enough to fix the problem.
If this has not helped, there are a few other things you can try:

5. If you used npm, install yarn (http://yarnpkg.com/) and repeat the above steps with it instead.
    This may help because npm has known issues with package hoisting which may get resolved in future versions.
6. Check if /home/hanna/node_modules/webpack is outside your project directory.
    For example, you might have accidentally installed something in your home folder.
7. Try running npm ls webpack in your project folder.
    This will tell you which other package (apart from the expected react-scripts) installed webpack.

If nothing else helps, add SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true to an .env file in your project.
That would permanently disable this preflight check in case you want to proceed anyway.

P.S. We know this message is long but please read the steps above :-) We hope you find them helpful!

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! my-todo-react@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the my-todo-react@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /home/hanna/.npm/_logs/2018-10-02T10_39_06_361Z-debug.log

Comment: How did you install Webpack? Since it looks like the project uses Create React App, Webpack is probably already a dependency in `package.json`. So the easy way to install it is to just go to the project directory and type `npm install` (or `yarn install`) in the terminal. If you installed it globally, you can uninstall it globally with `npm -g uninstall webpack`.

Comment: Yes. Webpack was already in package.json. But in terminal react requires older version of webpack. So I was searching a very long time. And after that I understood that webpack is installed globally. And I uninstalled it and in project folder installed that version that react requires. Thank you very much for answer

Comment: Great! Glad to hear it worked. I summarized the answer for other readers below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [NPM start returns error, "There might be a problem with the project dependency tree"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56528222/npm-start-returns-error-there-might-be-a-problem-with-the-project-dependency-t)

Answer (score 27):

Create a `.env` file in the root directory of the project and add this line `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true` inside the file.

then try to run `yarn start`.

Comment: This is the only solution that worked for me all other steps steps yielded nothing.

Comment: Well done bro, very simple solution, worked for me:)

Answer (score 20):

To solve this issue I had to uninstall webpack and webpack-dev-server from the node-modules folder and then install them again but with different versions.

1. Open cmd on the node-modules folder **outside of your project folder**
2. Uninstall webpack and webpack-dev-server:

   ```
   npm uninstall webpack
   npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
   ```
3. Delete the **node-modules** folder and the **package-lock.json** file from your project's folder.
4. Open the node-modules again

   ```
   npm install webpack@4.19.1
   npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.9
   ```
5. Use this command on your project folder

   ```
   npm install
   ```

It did the trick for me, hope it helps you too.

Comment: what is the webpack-dev-server for and why you installed different version than webpack?

Answer (score 6):

One solution I had was to go to my "Home" folder and delete the node_modules
folder and package-lock.json file.

Worked afterwards.

Comment: I remove my node_modules folder in "Home" and npm start work for me.

Comment: Good job! That was exactly my problem

Answer (score 4):

Since it looks like the project uses Create React App, Webpack is probably already a dependency in the `package.json`. So the easy way to install it is to just go to the project directory and type `npm install` (or `yarn install`) in the terminal.

If using the Webpack CLI causes errors, it's probably because there's a different version installed globally.

To uninstall it globally, type `npm -g uninstall webpack`.

Answer (score 4):

I had similar problem today. I resolved with the following steps:

1. Execute `npm ls webpack` --> to find out that I have installed Webpack outside my folder ("like yours ... /home/hanna/node_modules/webpack).
2. Then `cd` into that location (/home/hanna/node_modules/) and execute `npm install webpack@4.19.1`.
   That way I have the same version of Webpack like in my project folder.

After that, when I run `npm start`, it works fine.

Comment: I made it in similar way. I uninstalled webpack globally and installed 4.19 version locally in my project folder. Thanks for your answer.

Answer (score 4):

do this

first code in terminal this -->

```
 yarn add --dev dotenv
```

create `.env` file in root directory then add below line in the `.env` file

```
 SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```

Answer (score 3):

Go to your project directory where you are running `npm start` and run the command

`touch .env`

If there is no pre-existing .env file in your project this will create it.
Got to .env file and add the following code (if you are on LINUX box you do this by typing `nano .env` otherwise just use a text editor.
`SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`

Save the file and try running  `npm start` again.
This solution is exactly what is suggested in the error message and it worked for me

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue and following worked for me:

- Delete the node-modules folder and package-lock.json file
- Downloaded and installed Node.js
- `npm install webpack@4.19.1`
- `npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.9`
- Deleted babel-eslint entry from package.json
- Used this command on the project folder: `npm install`
- Finally `yarn start` or `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

If someone still facing this issue and uses yarn instead of npm can do (I am a mac user):

- Open a terminal
- Type `yarn remove webpack`
- Come in to your project directory using your file explorer
- Delete everything there
- Open your code-editor
- Delete hidden filers (ETC: .env or .gitignore files) if exists
- In your project directory open a terminal and type `npx
  create-react-app .` and hit enter.
- And restart the app typing `yarn start` after download.

It worked for me. It downloaded the web pack which is needed from react-scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Go to `/home/hanna` and type `npm i webpack@required_dependency`. It should solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

I think if you have a webpack package installed globally it might cause such error. Removing it globally might solve the problem. That's what I did here and it works.

```
npm uninstall webpack
npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
```

Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file from your root directory

```
##thompsonmax##
```

Then you can now run your command to your app,

```
create-react-app react-app
```

Answer (score 1):

- Step 1: Create an `.env` file in the root directory
- Step 2: add this line into your `.env` file: `SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true`
- Step 3:Again `npm start`

Answer (score 1):

After a lot of trials, I found that the **easiest solution** is to **install the required version of webpack** in /home/hanna.

That is,

1. cd to /home/hanna
2. run `npm i webpack@4.19.1`

Then, the error will go away. Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is you installed webpack version: 4.20.2

You need to install an earlier version   "webpack": "4.19.1"`

[image]

Your problem is you installed webpack version: 4.20.2

You need to install an earlier version   "webpack": "4.19.1"` ..So

```
$npm uninstall -g webpack
```

and

```
$npm install -g webpack@4.19.1
```

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find a way to uninstall the whole node module folder the only way is to delete the whole file using command line

```
rm -rf node_modules
```

Answer (score 0):

I think if you have a webpack package installed globally it might cause such error. Removing it globally might solve the problem. That's what I did here and it works.

Answer (score 0):

Due to newer versions, this worked for me:

1. Open a terminal window (command prompt) on the `node_modules` folder outside of your project folder
2. Uninstall `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server`:

   ```
   npm uninstall webpack
   npm uninstall webpack-dev-server
   ```
3. Delete the `node_modules` folder and the `package-lock.json` file from your project's folder.
4. Open `node_modules` again

   ```
   npm install webpack@4.28.3
   npm install webpack-dev-server@3.1.14
   ```
5. Use this command in your project folder:

   ```
   npm install
   ```

Answer (score 0):

- npx create-react-app **nameOfYourApp**
- find where is your **nameOfYourApp** and replace **src** folder with one from previous project
- use new **nameOfYourApp**

Answer (score 0):

## **If you have multiple node_modules folders with different versions of dependencies one may conflict with the other** -  do the following:

1. Follow steps 1-4 that are initially provided in project directory and commit updated changes locally~

---

i. Delete **package-lock.json** (not package.json!) and/or yarn.lock in your project folder.

ii. Delete **node_modules** in your project folder.

iii. Remove **webpack** from dependencies and/or **devDependencies** in the **package.json** file in your project folder.

iv. Run `npm install` or yarn, depending on the package manager you use.

2. Find the location of the **node_modules** folder that is not in your project folder ~ this line - (/home/hanna/node_modules/webpack)
3. Delete it
4. `npm start`

should work :)!

Answer (score 0):

I also faced this issue. I had to install `webpack@4.42.0` in the node_modules but after I installed `webpack@4.42.0` there was an error displayed in the CMD:

```
`-- UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY webpack@4.42.0

npm ERR! peer dep missing: webpack@^5.1.0, required by terser-webpack-plugin@5.2.4
```

So installing webpack for node_modules didn't work. Then I used `.env` file to solve this.

First I typed `npm add --dev dotenv` in the project terminal.
Then I created the `.env` file and typed this code:

```
SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK=true
```